How does the browser know when an element is fully rendered?
I've been working to improve Core Web Vitals metrics on my site. One metric I've improved is decreasing the Largest Contentful Paint time.
I've achieved this but using critical above-the-fold inline CSS - the theory being that the browser can style all elements (including the LCP element) above the fold faster as it is reading critical CSS without having to load an entire .css file first.
However, I had a question: how does the browser (or Google) know when an element has completed rendering?
For example and arguments sake, what if I had an element, say .lcp-content, and placed it's styles within the the above-the-fold inline CSS, but also included something like .lcp-content {color: red;} at the very bottom of my main.css file?
At what point does the browser/Google decide "yep, that element is fully rendered"?

LCP can change right up until the user navigates away from the page. However it is finalised on interactions: "The browser will stop reporting new entries as soon as the user interacts with the page (via a tap, scroll, or keypress), as user interaction often changes what's visible to the user (which is especially true with scrolling)."

I've achieved this but using critical above-the-fold inline CSS - the theory being that the browser can style all elements (including the LCP element) above the fold faster as it is reading critical CSS without having to load an entire .css file first.

A word of warning here. This is the fastest way of rendering content, but can be very tricky to implement correctly. You need to ensure the critical CSS is calculated correctly, and that the main.css file is also not render blocking. It is possible to do this correctly, but it's also very easy for this to break in the future and actually worsen the experience. I've seen more than a few sites with this. So just be aware of this complexity and the downsides before implementing this.

For example and arguments sake, what if I had an element, say .lcp-content, and placed it's styles within the the above-the-fold inline CSS, but also included something like .lcp-content {color: red;} at the very bottom of my main.css file?

In this particular example, the style will not affect the size of the content, and so a later LCP will not be reported. In general elements will only report their initial size for LCP, but there are some nuances and cases where that's not always true (especially when the size is changed changing which element is the LCP element and/or if the page is a JavaScript client-side rendered application and "hydrated").

At what point does the browser/Google decide "yep, that element is fully rendered"?

As I say "Google" decides on leaving the page for tools like the Chrome User Experience Report, which feeds PageSpeed Insights and Google Search Console.
